# $f(x)=x^p$ and Riemann sum

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

I have been tackling this for days and I am utterly confused on how to do this. I'd love to see how to work this out:

Let $0<a<b$ and $p$ be an element of the ℝ \ {-1}

**a)** Given a partition P = {$a=x_0< ... <x_n=b$} where $x_j=ar^{j/n}$ with $r=b/a$, show that for $f(x)=x^p$,

$\frac{b^{p+1}-a^{p+1}}{p+1}$ is equal to $\lim_{n\to∞}U(f,P_n)$ if $p>=0$, otherwise $\lim_{n\to∞}L(f,P_n)$ if $p<0$.

[Hint: Use geometric sums. You may have to compute $\lim_{t\to1}\frac{t-1}{t^{p+1}-1}$]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: To be honest, Im just confused. It seems like the value of p dictates the sign of (b^(p+1)-a^(p+1))/(p+1) which leads me to believe the upper and lower sums are different, and possibly the limits. But overall, I dont see how the geometric sums or how any of the equations come about. Im lost on this one...

Comment: The value of $p$ dictates whether the function $x^p$ is increasing or decreasing.  If it is increasing, then use the right-hand endpoints for upper sums, but if it is decreasing, use the left-hand endpoint. The other way for lower sums.

Comment: Is it possible I can still see at least how a) and b) are done? Im new to Riemann sums and integrability so Im not too sure what to do, even given your helpful information.

Comment: I realized I had a random variable k there. I hope this clarifies everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a**let $P={t_{0},t_{1}, \cdots,t_{n} }$ a partition of $[a,b]$:

let's define $M_{i}=f(t_{i})$ with $f(x)=x^{p}$ and $t_{i}=ac^{i/n}$, then;

$$U(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(t_{i}-t_{i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(ac^{\frac{i}{n}})^{p}(ac^{\frac{i}{n}}-ac^{\frac{i-1}{n}})$$
$$=a^{p+1}(1-c^{-\frac{1}{n}})\sum_{i=1}^{n}(c^{\frac{p+1}{n}})^{i}$$
$$=a^{p+1}(1-c^{-\frac{1}{n}})\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(c^{\frac{p+1}{n}})^{j+1}$$
$$=a^{p+1}(1-c^{-\frac{1}{n}})c^{\frac{p+1}{n}}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(c^{\frac{p+1}{n}})^{j}$$

then simplifying and using the geometric sum you have
$$(a^{p+1}-b^{p+1})c^{\frac{p}{n}}(\frac{c^\frac{1}{n}-1)}{1-c^{(p+1)/n}})$$, the you have that:
$$1+c^{1/n}+\cdots+c^p/n=\frac{1-c^{(n+1)/n}}{1-c^{1/n}}$$
$$\frac{-1}{1+c^{1/n}+\cdots+c^p/n}=\frac{c^{1/n}-1}{1-c^{(p+1)/n}}$$
$$=\frac{(b^{p+1}-a^{p+1})c^{p/n}}{1+c^{1/n}+\cdots+c^p/n}$$

similarly defines $L(f,P)$

to show that it is integrable, use the fact that;
$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$$, 
it's easy to see that $\int_{a}^{b}x^{p}=\frac{b^{(p+1)/n}-a^{(p+1)/n}}{1+p}$

Comment: I thank you so much for your answer. Also, is it possible you can just state what L(f,P) is equal to and just that? I'm new to this and seeing a clear difference between how U(f,P) and L(f,P) looks will help me understand these concepts a lot more!!!

Comment: $L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$, where $m_{i}=f(t_{i-1})$ is called lower sum.